# How to list childrens recursively in a GSP page?

Tags: grails, recursion, tags, gsp

i have a Media Domain

```
def Media {
   String name

   static belongsTo = [parent:Media]
   static hasMany = [children:Media]
}
```

In the show.gsp page i want to list all my root Media (that haven't parent) into an ul list an their children and their children recursively in another ul lists. I have used the  Tag for the first list but i don't know how to do this recursively for the children.

So have you an idea of how to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put the recursive part into a GSP-template and then call it recursively, e.g.:

`index.gsp`: Assuming `rootMedias` is passed into the view

```
<g:each in="${rootMedias}" var="media">
    <g:render template="step" model="${[media: media]}" />
</g:each>
```

`_step.gsp`

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${media.children}" var="child">
    <li>
        ${child.name}
        <g:render template="step" model="${[media: child]}" />
    </li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just an FYI - you don't need the `${}` around the map you send as the model

Comment: Thank you for this very userful response.